# ASP.NET MVC FormsAuthentication Cookie timeout cannot be increased

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

Using the default ASP.NET MVC template, I cannot figure out how to increase the FormsAuthentication timeout.  It seems to always use 30 minutes.

I have followed Scott Gu's recommendation from [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/08/430011.aspx), but it does not seem to make a difference.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

His suggestion was to set the timeout value in the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My issue was only occurring in my production environment at my web host.

I found [this link](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) and generated a machine key to put in the web.config.  Once I did that, the timeout value took effect.

Comment: The link loads content in some Asian language. Not English

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and adding a custom MachineKey with a ValidationKey to the web.config solved the problem. It seems to affect shared hosts.

I used this site to generate a random machine key:
http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are setting this in the ~/Web.config file and not in the ~/Views/Web.config file.  Also, 50 million minutes is approx. 100 years, which might be hitting some date-related overflow in the browser.  Try using a more reasonable number like 2 - 3 years (1.5 million minutes).

Comment: Those are good suggestions. However, I wasn't actually using the large timeout value. I had it set to something more reasonable like 2 days. As far as the location of the web.config, I do have the setting in the appropriate file. I believe that setting exists by default in the ASP.NET MVC template, so I have not moved it.