# Getting logged out in short time in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I have received complaints from users that they are getting logged out after a relatively short time.

I have the following settings in `web.config` but apparently it does not work.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209618/1849444)

So you should place machine key in your Web.Config. Ex:

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <machineKey decryptionKey="F6722806843145965513817CEBDECBB1F94808E4A6C0B2F2,IsolateApps" validationKey="C551753B0325187D1759B4FB055B44F7C5077B016C02AF674E8DE69351B69FEFD045A267308AA2DAB81B69919402D7886A6E986473EEEC9556A9003357F5ED45,IsolateApps" /> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

You can learn how to generate machine key [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! But the link in his example is not leading anywhere.

Comment: Yes, i know, that's why i provide other links how to generate machine key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want user stays login until his/her browser is open, I do a trick. I create an Action or any Handler like below, it just return some dummy text (ex: `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`), and then use `jQuery.get` to request this. I keeps user login because browser keep sends requests:

Handler:

```
public class KeepAlive : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

MVC Action:

```
public bool KeppChecking()
{
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.get('/Ajax/KeepAlive.ashx');
}, 10000);
```