# ASP.NET MVC5 Authenication on login

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, web-applications, authorization

I am trying to setup the Login authentication for a new enterprise site, I am trying to run the user login from my server's database (rather than the build in azure stuff.

I use the [Authorize] Header in my Controllers

```
public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            [Authorize]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

This is my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index")
    });
```

Then in my Login Controller where I setup the AuthCookie:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string Error)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string userID, string password)
{
    if(CheckUserCredentialsAgainstDB(userID, password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userID, true);
    }
}
```

When I run the The application and log in, I have the .ASPAUTH cookie in my browser, but when I attempt to access an action with the [Authorize] tag it sends me straight back to the Login Page, what am I missing here?

There are similiar questions to this such as [Persistent AuthCookie is set but being redirected to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922761/persistent-authcookie-is-set-but-being-redirected-to-login), however none of the answers have helped in my scenario.

Comment: According to the link you posted, Cookie setter is not enough to keep you authenticated, so I guess it's normal it's not working. Can't help you more if you have tried the suggested things in the link

Comment: You are mixing OWIN Cookies Authentication with old Forms Authentication, which are two different things. What is that you really want?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma thanks I was not aware they were different! I think my question still stands (I thought I was using the Forms Authenication method) how do I generate an auth cookie that can be correctly picked up by the [Authorize] tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms Authentication is a different thing than OWIN default cookies auth.

Your login method should rely on the `IAuthenticationManager` exposed by `OwinContext` to sign in the user correctly:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string userID, string password)
{
    if(CheckUserCredentialsAgainstDB(userID, password))
    {
        var claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userID),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "therole")
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); // create a new user identity

        var auth = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        auth.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = false // set to true if you want `remember me` feature
        }, identity);

        // redirect the user somewhere
    }

    // notify the user of failure
}
```

#### Side notes

Do not use multiple parameters in POST methods, especially when posting sensitive data like login information.

Basic parameters are usually transmitted inside the query string, and they will be visible by anyone by just looking at the URL (this means also inside server logs).

Instead, use a simple View Model to obtain the same result:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// ...

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if(CheckUserCredentialsAgainstDB(model.UserId, model.Password))
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Federico you're advice led to this article which solved my problem! [Setting up OWIN login auth](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application)